# Probability prime numbers test

Tags: probability

We have probability prime numbers test which give following answers:

1. if number is prime, the answer is: NO KNOWING
2. if number is composite, the answer is: NO KNOWING with
   probability $1/2$ and NUMBER IS COMPOSITE with probability $1/2$
3. if we use test over and over again we receive independent results

Suppose that we have set with $99,9 \%$ composite numbers and $0,1 \%$ with prime numbers. We draw from one number and use this test $n$-times. In every case we received answer: NO KNOWING.

How is it probability that the number is prime?

I think that is $p_n = \frac{0,001}{0,001 + 0,999 \cdot \frac{1}{2^n} } = \frac{2^n}{2^n + 999} $, but I'm not sure. I will grateful for check it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a canonical conditional probability problem, more interesting than many. We can do it formally or informally, and  opt for the formal.

Let $P$ be the event the number is prime, and $D$ the event getting "Don't know" $n$ times. We want $\Pr(P|D)$. By the defining formula for conditional probability, we have
$$|Pr(P|D)=\frac{\Pr(P\cap D)}{\Pr(D)}.$$

We have $\Pr(P\cap D)=0.001$. For the denominator, there are two disjoint ways the event $D$ can happen: (i) the number is prime and $D$ happens or (ii) the number is not prime and $D$ happens. The probability of (i) has already been computed, it is $0.001$. The probability of (ii) is $(0.999)(2^{-n})$.

Thus we obtain precisely the expression you wrote down.